# Displaying List after button click

Tags: android

I am developing an android application.I have a search bar where i put search string and using search string entered after clicking search button,i fetch values from database(SQLite) and display in list.

What i want to do is i want to display list below search bar only after search button is clicked.How should i do this.?Please look in to this.

Comment: Set your `ListView`'s visibility to gone/invisible from start, then change it to visible on the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an `OnClickListener` for the search button.

In the `onClick` method change the visibility settings of the listView to `VISIBLE`

Comment: I have done like that bt problem occurs as follows...When I click search button  list is displayed which is in portrait mode...then when i move to landscape mode list is automatically invisible..i nedd to click search button to display list items..

Comment: thats because you activity get's destroyed and recreated. So you need to save your preference's - like say - list is currently being shown. Then when your activity is created again, check the preference if the list was shown previously you can make it visible or else it stays hidden.

Comment: Hi ravi,thanks for your reply...How to check preferences if the list is previously visible....

Comment: check this [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)